# How to make Story and saved story in one table MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made three tables `users`, `stories` (linked to user), `saved_stories` (linked to user).

In web page when someone saves the story and don't publish it will save in saved_stories.

Is it possible to use one stories table and make the task?

Comment: Yes. Add a `published` column to your `stories` table with a default of `0` _(not published)_ and then switch it to `1` _Published_ when it gets published